# Проблема с интеграцией API Woocomerce в React

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, api, woocommerce

Привет!Я хотел получать данные в свой сайт на React через API,сделал все как сказано в документации,выполнил установку `npm install --save woocommerce-api`, создал обьект с параметрами как в документации http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#pagination

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import WooCommerceAPI from 'woocommerce-api';


class Goods extends Component {
    WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: 'http://portland.com/wp/', // Your store URL
    consumerKey: 'ck_c221d7f97defb2d3a045730b8a0ff470327180a6', // Your consumer key
    consumerSecret: 'cs_33cdde6ad3a4583624478504b86ee8fd7844b394', // Your consumer secret
    wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
    version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  });
    render() {
        return(
        <div className="GoodsMain">
            <div className="Goods">
            <img src="/images/photo.png" alt="appletv"/><br/>
            <div className="TextAlign">
            <span className="NameOfGood">{WooCommerce.get('products/1').name}</span><br/>
            <span className="StyleOfGood">black</span><br/>
            <span className="PriceOfGood">$49.99</span>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        );
    }
}


export default Goods;
```

Но я получаю `Line 20:  'WooCommerce' is not defined  no-undef`.Можете показать как правильно использовать WooComerce API в React.

Comment: **var** WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI(...

Comment: Спасибо но как оказалось нужно подключать плагин в Back-end и него передавать данные на React."React is front-end, the WooCommerce API is backend. What you need to do is use the API in node.js or PHP or Ruby. Then in your React app, you make requests to your own backend (which grabs wordpress data using the WooCommerce API and forwards it to your React client)."Теперь сижу учи node.js:)